# How can I strip punctuation from a string?

Tags: c#, string

For the hope-to-have-an-answer-in-30-seconds part of this question, I'm specifically looking for C#

But in the general case, what's the best way to strip punctuation in any language?

**I should add:** Ideally, the solutions won't require you to enumerate all the possible punctuation marks.

Related: [Strip Punctuation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Different languages are, in fact, different, and I don't think there's an answer to the question you're asking.  You could ask about specific languages, or what language would be best for that sort of manipulation.

Answer (score 120):

```
new string(myCharCollection.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Yup.  It's powering the string operation I posted below.

Comment: LinQ never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Brilliant. Less is more.

Comment: doesnt work on $ or ^, maybe more. I'm sticking with ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$

Comment: PhoneNumberTextBox.Text = new string(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray()).Replace(" ","");

Comment: for $ or ^ u can use  `!char.IsSymbol(c)` validation. just for the record

Answer (score 26):

Why not simply:

```
string s = "sxrdct?fvzguh,bij.";
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in s)
{
   if (!char.IsPunctuation(c))
      sb.Append(c);
}

s = sb.ToString();
```

The usage of RegEx is normally slower than simple char operations. And those LINQ operations look like overkill to me. And you can't use such code in .NET 2.0...

Comment: Note that this approach also lets you replace punctuation with (for example) whitespace.  Useful for tokenizing.

Answer (score 16):

Describes intent, easiest to read (IMHO) and best performing:

```
 s = s.StripPunctuation();
```

to implement:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string StripPunctuation(this string s)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (!char.IsPunctuation(c))
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is using Hades32's algorithm which was the best performing of the bunch posted.

Comment: interesting tidbit: the following are not punctuation: $^+|<>=

Answer (score 14):

Assuming "best" means "simplest" I suggest using something like this:

```
String stripped = input.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
```

This example is for [Java,](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) but all sufficiently modern Regex engines should support this (or something similar).

Edit: the Unicode-Aware version would be this:

```
String stripped = input.replaceAll("\\p{P}+", "");
```

The first version only looks at punctuation characters contained in ASCII.

Comment: C# doesn't have the `Punct` class but it does have `P`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the regex.replace method:

```
 replace(YourString, RegularExpressionWithPunctuationMarks, Empty String)
```

Since this returns a string, your method will look something like this:

```
 string s = Regex.Replace("Hello!?!?!?!", "[?!]", "");
```

You can replace "[?!]" with something more sophiticated if you want:

```
(\p{P})
```

This should find any punctuation.

Comment: +1 for using a unicode character class. Concise, precise, and nice.

Answer (score 6):

This thread is so old, but I'd be remiss not to post a more elegant (IMO) solution.

```
string inputSansPunc = input.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + c);
```

It's LINQ sans WTF.

Answer (score 4):

Based off GWLlosa's idea, I was able to come up with the supremely ugly, but working:

> ```
> string s = "cat!";
> s = s.ToCharArray().ToList<char>()
>       .Where<char>(x => !char.IsPunctuation(x))
>       .Aggregate<char, string>(string.Empty, new Func<string, char, string>(
>              delegate(string s, char c) { return s + c; }));
> ```

Comment: I know; right?  I hobby of mine is committing sins against code in Linq.  But please, by all means, make it better.

Comment: Please seek psychiatric help.

Comment: That's quadratic in the length in s; if you double the length, the code will be four times slower, because the + operator for string has to make a copy of the string :/

Answer (score 2):

The most braindead simple way of doing it would be using string.replace

The other way I would imagine is a regex.replace and have your regular expression with all the appropriate punctuation marks in it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach using linq. I like AviewAnew's but this avoids the Aggregate

```
        string myStr = "Hello there..';,]';';., Get rid of Punction";

        var s = from ch in myStr
                where !Char.IsPunctuation(ch)
                select ch;

        var bytes = UnicodeEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s.ToArray());
        var stringResult = UnicodeEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Why the `IEnumerable<char>` to array to bytes to string conversion, why not just `new String(s.ToArray())`? Or is that what new string will do under the hood anyway?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this for tokenizing text you can use:

```
new string(myText.Select(c => char.IsPunctuation(c) ? ' ' : c).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who would like to do this via RegEx:

This code shows the full RegEx replace process and gives a sample Regex that only keeps letters, numbers, and spaces in a string - replacing ALL other characters with an empty string:

```
//Regex to remove all non-alphanumeric characters
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex TitleRegex = new 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-z0-9 ]+", 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string ParsedString = TitleRegex.Replace(stringToParse, String.Empty);

return ParsedString;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and was concerned about the performance impact of calling the IsPunctuation for every single check.

I found this post: http://www.dotnetperls.com/char-ispunctuation.

Accross the lines: char.IsPunctuation also handles Unicode on top of ASCII.
The method matches a bunch of characters including control characters. By definiton, this method is heavy and expensive.

The bottom line is that I finally didn't go for it because of its performance impact on my ETL process.

I went for the custom implemetation of dotnetperls.

And jut FYI, here is some code deduced from the previous answers to get the list of all punctuation characters (excluding the control ones):

```
var punctuationCharacters = new List<char>();

        for (int i = char.MinValue; i <= char.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            var character = Convert.ToChar(i);

            if (char.IsPunctuation(character) && !char.IsControl(character))
            {
                punctuationCharacters.Add(character);
            }
        }

        var commaSeparatedValueOfPunctuationCharacters = string.Join("", punctuationCharacters);

        Console.WriteLine(commaSeparatedValueOfPunctuationCharacters);
```

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

```
$newstr=ereg_replace("[[:punct:]]",'',$oldstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For long strings I use this:

```
var normalized = input
                .Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c))
                .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                           (current, next) => current.Append(next), sb => sb.ToString());
```

performs much better than using string concatenations (though I agree it's less intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code for removing punctuation from strings given by the user

### Import required library

```
    import string
```

### Ask input from user in string format

```
    strs = str(input('Enter your string:'))

    for c in string.punctuation:
        strs= strs.replace(c,"")
    print(f"\n Your String without punctuation:{strs}")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<string>
    #include<cctype>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int a, char* b[]){
    string strOne = "H,e.l/l!o W#o@r^l&d!!!";
    int punct_count = 0;

cout<<"before : "<<strOne<<endl;
for(string::size_type ix = 0 ;ix < strOne.size();++ix)   
{   
    if(ispunct(strOne[ix])) 
    {
            ++punct_count;  
            strOne.erase(ix,1); 
            ix--;
    }//if
}
    cout<<"after : "<<strOne<<endl;
                  return 0;
    }//main
```