# Keep list of separated marks from string

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm trying to figure out with `linq` and `regex` method, to remove all alphabetic and numeric characters and keep only punctuation marks in string:

```
   string input = ": hello; world; 2019>how?.are,you. .i'm good}and-you[?ok";
```

to  split in output list for each mark not divided by char or number in same string:

```
:
;
;
>
?.
,
..
'
}
-
[?
```

Any guide or example would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use the following

**Given**

```
string input = ": hello; world; 2019>how?.are,you. .i'm good}and-you[?ok";
```

**Option 1**

```
var results = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\w]", Environment.NewLine)
                   .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(x => x.Replace(" ", ""));
```

**Option 2**

```
var results2 = Regex.Matches(input, @"[\p{P} ]*")
                    .OfType<Match>()
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value))
                    .Select(x => x.Value.Replace(" ", ""));
```

**Output**

```
:
;
;
>
?.
,
.
.
'
}
-
[?
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/tw9IWY)

<sub>***Note** : There are probably better ways to do this in the one pattern*</sub>

Comment: Hello, both methods works exactly as described with only  exception, splits dots `. .` by white space divided, except `..` keeping both in one string

Comment: Option 2  answers to my question for 100%. Option 1 `.Select(x => x.Value.Replace(" ", ""));` _Non-invocable member 'Select' cannot be used like a method_.

Comment: @sam324 fixed option one

Comment: Did you tried with Option 1, because it still show the same Non-invocable member, must be check once again

Comment: yes, both methods gives proper result, Option 2  gives correct result according to my question and desired output

Answer (score 0):

With Linq, you can use something very similar to [this response on how to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421616/how-can-i-strip-punctuation-from-a-string), you could use:

```
var result = input.Where(p => char.IsPunctuation(p)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hello, works good if I want keep and split marks for each separate, but not for several exist between numbers or character  for single string